# Remove number of keys from multidimensional array without loop

Tags: php

I want to remove keys like `id`, `group_id`, `star_rating`  from below multidimensional array in php

I can already done using below code with for loop and it's work but It will be good if not use any single loop, try to give solution with use of built-in php function

#### Working code but don't want to use loop

```
$data = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $subArr) {
    unset($subArr['id']);
    unset($subArr['group_id']);
    unset($subArr['star_rating']);
    $data[$key] = $subArr;  
}

print_r($data);
```

#### Input :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 128
            [receiver_id] => 18
            [group_id] => 
            [tipper_id] => 
            [amount] => 150
            [tip_type] => 3
            [star_rating] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 129
            [receiver_id] => 16
            [group_id] => 
            [tipper_id] => 12
            [amount] => 600
            [tip_type] => 2
            [star_rating] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 130
            [receiver_id] => 14
            [group_id] => 
            [tipper_id] => 18
            [amount] => 750
            [tip_type] => 1
            [star_rating] => 
        )

)
```

After remove specify keys (id, group_id, star_rating) result will display :

#### Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [receiver_id] => 18
            [tipper_id] => 
            [amount] => 150
            [tip_type] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [receiver_id] => 16
            [tipper_id] => 12
            [amount] => 600
            [tip_type] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [receiver_id] => 14
            [tipper_id] => 18
            [amount] => 750
            [tip_type] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: And can you show us your attempt at acheiving this requirement?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with asking for help with your homework. But dont ask us to do it all for you. Where is the benefit in that to you anyway

Comment: It's not homework.  i can able to solve this with for lopp but i don't want   that    I want create another array in which i want to remove specific number of keys to pass for datatable @RiggsFolly

Comment: @JatinKaklotar can you add you existing attempts to your question? Anyway `array_map` would be the declarative way of your existing code which is probably written in an imperative way.

Comment: @ChristophKluge i have updated my answer can you please give me answer how to do with `array_map` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i have done using `array_map`

```
$data = array_map(
   function (array $subArr) {
      unset($subArr['id']);
      unset($subArr['group_id']);
      unset($subArr['star_rating']);
      return $subArr;
   },
   $array
);

print_r($data);
```